# Total market size of structured products

Tags: structured-finance

Is there any number or estimate for the total notional in structured products in the market? I could only find figures for Germany.

What about across categories? I.e. Equity linked notes, index linked notes exc. exc.

Comment: You mean the total notional of structured debt emitted by a particular entity ?

Comment: @MJ73550 in the market, I'll update the post to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of global figures. But for the European market for structured products, you can have a look at [www.eusipa.org](http://www.eusipa.org). They aggregate the national figures, including the German ones that you probably found on [www.derivateverband.de](http://www.derivateverband.de).